# Where to download Ubuntu without bittorrent

Tags: downloads

Please could someone tell me where can I download Ubuntu 32bit without using a torrent?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it straight from ubuntu.com using this link:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Or for the i386 specifically (32-bit)

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=16.04&architecture=i386